# Determinant for the exponential of a real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

How to prove not using complex matrices that for a real quadratic matrix $X$ we have $\det(\exp(X))=\exp(\operatorname{Tr} X)$?
A proof which I know use the fact that such a matrix is similar  with triangular complex matrix.

Comment: I think that you forgot a $\det$ in your expression.

Comment: Yes, I have just corrected.

Comment: What is a quadratic matrix?

Comment: @RGS My guess is that the OP meant square matrix.

Comment: @Alex Would you be interested in an answer based upon [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)?

Comment: Yes. I am interested.